# Preserve HTML tab across reload

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

I am knew to html and javascript. I am trying to change the below code on the JavaScript part to ensure when i reload the page, it doesn't go back to the first tab. When i click the second tab for "Paris" and refresh page, it goes back to "London" as the active tab. How do can i amend the JavaScript code below to keep the most recent active tab after reload? i got the code from w3school: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tabs

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}


/* Style the tab */

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

````html
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Tabs</h2>
  <p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
  </div>

  <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>London</h3>
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Paris</h3>
    <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Tokyo</h3>
    <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
  </div>


</body>

</html>

```
````

Comment: you have 2 options, store the current active tab in the url or store it in local storage

Comment: Thanks, how do I achieve that?

Comment: I read about local storage and that is the path I would prefer. I've just been struggling for 2 days to implement it.

Comment: well there are a lot of tutorials websites out there sadly stackoverflow is not one of them, you are welcome to post a question if you get stuck on a particular feature. I would start with storing and reading from localstorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/MoloF/eoxc4w53/27/), allowed only on jsFiddle

```js
const tablinks = document.querySelectorAll('button.tablinks');
const contents = document.querySelectorAll('.tabcontent');
const tabAlreadyExists = localStorage.getItem('tab-name');

const openCityHandle = function() {
 const targetTabName = this.dataset.tabName;

 contents.forEach(content => {
  const tabName = content.dataset.tabName;
  const display = targetTabName === tabName ? 'block' : 'none';
  content.style.display = display;
 });
 
 tablinks.forEach(tab => {
  const tabName = tab.dataset.tabName;
  const action = targetTabName === tabName ? 'add' : 'remove';
  tab.classList[action]('active');
 });
 
 localStorage.setItem('tab-name', targetTabName);
};

const openCityFromLocalStorageHandle = (tabName) => {
 const tab = document.querySelector(`button.tablinks[data-tab-name="${tabName}"]`);
 const content = document.querySelector(`.tabcontent[data-tab-name="${tabName}"]`);
 
 tab.classList.add('active');
 content.style.display = 'block';
};

if (tabAlreadyExists)
 openCityFromLocalStorageHandle(tabAlreadyExists);

tablinks.forEach(tablink => tablink.addEventListener('click', openCityHandle));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}


/* Style the tab */

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>Tabs</h2>
<button onclick="location.reload()">reload</button>
<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<div class="tab">
 <button class="tablinks" data-tab-name="London">London</button>
 <button class="tablinks" data-tab-name="Paris">Paris</button>
 <button class="tablinks" data-tab-name="Tokyo">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div class="tabcontent" data-tab-name="London">
 <h3>London</h3>
 <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>
<div class="tabcontent" data-tab-name="Paris">
 <h3>Paris</h3>
 <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>
<div class="tabcontent" data-tab-name="Tokyo">
 <h3>Tokyo</h3>
 <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```